# Is there easy way to do login using data from sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, model-view-controller

I stuck with my homework. I need to do make login page using asp.net MVC and data from SQL table. I found alot of tutorials on net but doesnt help because I dont need to make registration page and then login I just need to write some data in sql like for example userName= User1 password: 1234 and  with that login on page that I made using MVC. Btw I already connect
mvc and sql using entity framework. Just cant login using data from sql. Help pls.

Comment: "cant login using data from sql" what does that mean? Please clarify.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [this helpful article on what is considered necessary for a good SQL question](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson In my case I have SQL data table with few fields  ID,NAME,LAST NAME, Username, Password. I need to add data in table via SQL MANAGMENT STUDIO and with that  added Username and password login to mvc web page.

Comment: Then I understand that part but the question as whole is very unclear, please review the other comments given.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I can post whole code but problem is that variables and fields are not on english im not sure will it help you?